# Get highest level P131 for given place on Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata, data-collection

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
?place
?place_eng
?admin_eng
?country_eng
WHERE {
  VALUES ?place { wd:Q3437 wd:Q1903 wd:Q5083 }
  ?place wdt:P131 ?admin.
  ?place wdt:P17 ?country.
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,en".
    ?place rdfs:label ?place_eng.
    ?admin rdfs:label ?admin_eng.
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_eng.
  }
}
```

This yields the data:

| place | place_eng | admin_eng | country_eng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wd:Q1903 | Catania | Metropolitan City of Catania | Italy |
| wd:Q3437 | Perugia | Province of Perugia | Italy |
| wd:Q5083 | Seattle | King County | United States of America |

As you can see under `admin_eng`, this includes the first administrative area the city is in, through the P131 (located in the administrative territorial entity) property of the place.

Instead of it, I would like to obtain the **highest level** administrative area the place is in, like the state in the case of cities in the USA or the region in the case of Italian ones. For example:

| place | place_eng | admin_eng | country_eng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wd:Q1903 | Catania | **Sicily** | Italy |
| wd:Q3437 | Perugia | **Umbria** | Italy |
| wd:Q5083 | Seattle | **Washington** | United States of America |

I understand that I will need to go up the chain of P131 to do this, but I don't know how to tell the query to stop when the next level is the country itself, or how to do any of this at all, really. I'm almost a complete beginner at SPARQL and Wikidata.

I would also need the solution to be as efficient as possible, since I need to run this on many records, but a solution that works is a good start.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT
?place
?place_eng
?admin_eng
?country_eng
WHERE {
  VALUES ?place { wd:Q3437 wd:Q1903 wd:Q5083 }
  ?place wdt:P131+ ?admin. ?admin wdt:P131 ?country .
  ?place wdt:P17 ?country.
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,en".
    ?place rdfs:label ?place_eng.
    ?admin rdfs:label ?admin_eng.
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_eng.
  }
}`

Comment: I think the issue with this is that you need at least two instances of `wdt:P131` in the data for this to work. This will not be the case for cities in small countries, like Vaduz (`wd:Q1844`).
Now my answer below also does not work for Vaduz, but that's because Liechtenstein is listed as being in the German Confederation, which it is no longer in, so a data issue that will presumably be resolved in due course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution which doesn't require any backtracking:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?start ?admin
WHERE {
  VALUES ?start { wd:Q3437 wd:Q1903 wd:Q5083 }
  ?start wdt:P131+ ?admin.
  ?admin wdt:P131 ?temp.
  ?temp wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
}
```

This selects distinct results starting from the given values, recursively looking through the chain of administrations each belongs to (so, going all the way up to the country), then takes those administrations which have themselves an administration (`?temp`), which has to be an instance of country (so they must be a first-level administrative unit).

The following also works, but traverses the chain backwards:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?start ?admin
WHERE {
  VALUES ?start { wd:Q3437 wd:Q1903 wd:Q5083 }
  ?start wdt:P131+ ?admin.
  ?temp ^wdt:P131 ?admin;
         wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
}
```

I'm not able to tell whether it would be slower, faster, or equivalent to the other version. If anyone knows, please comment.

Answer (score 2):

This query seems to work quite well for me:
Edited answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
?place
?place_eng
?admin_eng
?country_eng
WHERE {
  VALUES ?place { wd:Q3437 }
  ?place wdt:P131+ ?admin .
  
  ?admin wdt:P131 ?country ;
         wdt:P17 ?country .
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
    ?place rdfs:label ?place_eng.
    ?admin rdfs:label ?admin_eng.
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_eng.
  }
}
```

Notice that `wdt:P131+`: this means one ore more instances of the property should occur. Then we make sure that we connect `?admin` and ?`country` with two different edges, `wdt:P17` i.e. 'has country', and `wdt:P131`, i.e. 'has administrative unit'.
This makes sure that `?admin` is directly below `?country`, and that `?country` is indeed a country.

Comment: Interesting; this seems like a great trick to know. But I was actually interested in the first level of administration *within* the country, so for example an Italian region. Is there a way to modify that filter to stop one level down, instead of right at the top (country) level?

Comment: So this query works, and it simply makes sure that the admin you pick is directly under its country. Performance is quite poor, so I had to restrict it to one value one:
https://w.wiki/3Hiz

Comment: Thank you. If you edit the answer to include this query (or add a new answer) I'll mark it as accepted. Could you explain what is happening on the line of the semicolon? I don't quite understand the syntax there.

Comment: Yes sure. The semicolon means that you keep the same subject, i.e. `?s ?p1 ?o1 ; ?p2 ?o2` is exactly the same as `?s ?p1 ?o1 . ?s ?p2 ?o2`. I'll put this in my answer too

Comment: However, I would really appreciate if you or someone else could improve the query to be more performant, hoping this is possible at all. It seems to time out for as little as 100 values, whereas my (sadly incorrect) initial query can process 5000. I need to run this on more than 200k values in total... :(

Comment: I'm afraid the engine behind Wikidata restricts resource usage, so anything too complex is hard to do. You could think about downloading the whole dataset and loading it into your own triplestore.

Comment: I've been testing the query with just three random values ( https://w.wiki/3HwT ) and it seems to time out even just with two. This seems abnormal; is it really so expensive a query that even two values should make it time out?

Comment: Try playing with optimisers here https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/query_optimization

Comment: I've been trying a different approach, hoping for better results: when I fetch a place, I get the wikidata id of its P131 and save it separately so that I can send a query for just those, checking if they're the top level subdivision of a country, and if not, get the next level. But I've fiddled with this and other queries without finding one that works as I wish. Could you lend me a hand with it?